# All arguments should have the same length plotly

Tags: python, plotly, data-analysis

I try to do a bar graph using plotly.express but I find this problem

> All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y`
> is 51, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['x'] is
> 4399
> and this my code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df= pd.read_csv('...../datasets-723010-1257097-fatal-police-shootings-data1.csv.xls')
c = df['state'].value_counts()
fig =px.bar(c , x = df['state'])
fig.show()
```

and this sample of data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV1no.png)

Comment: Provide sample of `df` data otherwise problem is not reproducible.

Comment: i added just click  on enter image description here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df['state']` has all the rows from the dataframe while `c` only contains a row for each unique value of state. you should use `c.index` instead:

```
px.bar(y=c, x=c.index)
```